# Add table row before or after a table row of known ID

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

In a table like this:

```
<table>
<!-- Insert Row of bun here -->
  <tr id="meat">
   <td>Hamburger</td>
  </tr>
<!-- Insert Row of bun here -->
</table>

function AddBefore(rowId){}
function AddAfter(rowId){}
```

I need to create methods without using jQuery.. I am familiar with append after and append before in jQuery.. but I am stuck with using plain js.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use

```
function AddBefore(rowId){
    var target = document.getElementById(rowId);
    var newElement = document.createElement('tr');
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, target);
    return newElement;
}

function AddAfter(rowId){
    var target = document.getElementById(rowId);
    var newElement = document.createElement('tr');

    target.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, target.nextSibling );
    return newElement;
}
```

Comment: @Gaby you should probably return the created row so that it may be used. Further, no need to use `appendChild`; this functionality is included in `insertBefore` when the second param is `null`.

Comment: @Phrogz, i can't recreate what you say .. see http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/d27wp/

Comment: @Gaby: I noticed parentElement / parentNode abnormality in IE7/FF

Comment: @Perpetualcoder, parentNode is the crossbrowser one. IS shoul support it just fine since it is in DOM 1 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534328%28VS.85%29.aspx).. will look into it..

Answer (score 1):

You want [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore). Use with `nextSibling` to insert after a known element.

Comment: forgot to say i am also stuck with IE7.. I am gonna try if that works in IE7.. thanks!

Comment: @Perpetualcoder It is supported; see the MSDN list of DHTML Methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533053(v=vs.85).aspx